# Select elements based on layout in Cypress

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, playwright

I am looking for a solution that can work like the following code in Playwright.

```js
page.click('input:right-of(:text("Username"))');
```

By using this command in Playwright, the input element on the right side of text `Username` will be clicked. I searched for a while but found that there seemed to be no handy equivalents in Cypress. Are there any approaches that can enable the possibility to select elements based on their positional relationships?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
cy.contains('Username')    // === :text("Username")
  .next()                  // === :right-of(<previous subject>)
  .click()
```

There may be subtle differences, like `.contains()` is a partial match and `.next()` is the next sibling in the DOM, not necessarily "right-of" by x coordinates.

---

You can add-in [cypress-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro/#examples) which has

```
cy.findByLabelText('Username').type('myname')
```

I haven't used it, but semantically seems to be what you are aiming for. Would be useful if relative positions change in mobile mode (e.g labels above).

A while back I implemented custom commands to assert relative positions of elements, as we were getting a lot of CSS regressions, but it's quite fiddly.

Comment: Thank you! But yeah, in my use case, I need to get the doms based on their positional relationships and many of them are not siblings...